# Working with Polymer 2.0 and require

Tags: javascript, node.js, polymer-2.x, ajv

I am trying to incorporate the JSON Schema validator [ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) into a Polymer 2.0 component.  It can be loaded with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv)

```
npm install ajv
```

I am having a problem instantiating ajv within a Polymer 2.0 component.

Accessing ajv is done through the require:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = new Ajv(); // options can be passed, e.g. {allErrors: true}
var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
```

How do I incorporate ajv within my Polymer 2.0 element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.  It is at https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/issues/21.  I needed to use browserify.

```
npm install -g browserify

browserify -r ./node_modules/ajv/lib/ajv.js:ajv -o ./node_modules/ajv/lib/bundle.js
```

In the html file:

```
<script src="../../node_modules/ajv/lib/bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  Ajv                  = require('ajv')
  , ajv                  = Ajv();
</script>
```